# Bootstrap 5: inline aligning divs without changing container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've been working on finding a solution to this, and cannot seem to find anything that works. I am trying to make some general components for a system using Bootstrap 5, and have defined a button as:

```
<div class="col buttonDiv">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
</div>
```

When users place this in their container in the system, it automatically generates an outer container:

```
<div class="divContainer">
//button
</div>
```

So, if the users try to place 2 buttons, the code will look like:

```
<div class="divContainer">
<div class="col buttonDiv">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="divContainer">
<div class="col buttonDiv">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I inline these buttons and also be able to change the alignment on them? It is not possible for me to add classes to the outer container of the divContainers.

I hope someone can shed some light on this problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: You can use display flex on the parent container which align them on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

use `Bootstrap 5` class `d-inline` to align them [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#examples) here

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="divContainer d-inline">
    <div class="col buttonDiv d-inline">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divContainer d-inline">
    <div class="col buttonDiv d-inline">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="divContainer d-inline">
<div class="divContainer d-inline">
        <div class="col buttonDiv d-inline">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divContainer d-inline">
        <div class="col buttonDiv d-inline">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo Bar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're missing an important part of the html, which is that there are two divContainers around each of the buttonDivs. But suppose I could get this to work, how do I align the buttons?

Comment: @Simone i updated my answer with two containers

Comment: Thank you, but then how do I change the alignment of the buttons? I've tried with both justify-content and align-content and its not working

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Example Code -->
    
    <div class="d-flex">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block">Foo Bar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block ms-2">Foo Bar</button>
    </div>
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block">Foo Bar</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block ms-2">Foo Bar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing an important part. The buttons are not in the same div, and I cannot make them be in the same div.